# Misunderstanding of arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, rsa

First of all, this is not a "here is my code, what is the problem?" question. Instead it is a "here is my code, this is the problem, what part of arrays have I misunderstood?". I am hoping that the difference between those questions means that this post won't annoy too many people; I'm hoping to improve my knowledge not get other people to do work for me.

The problem that I am having I am sure is due to a fundamental (hopefully easy to explain) problem in my understanding of how arrays work. I'm self-taught and my question has been too specific for me to find any help from Google.

I'll quickly explain what the each part of my code does in case it is important, sorry if this is irrelevant (it is **supposed** to be the encryption portion of an RSA algorithm):

```
int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x - 87;
}
```

This converts letters to numbers, with a=10, b=11, ... z=35.

```
unsigned long long modExp(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m)
{
unsigned long long remainder;
int x = 1;

while (e != 0)
{
remainder = e % 2;
e= e/2;

if (remainder == 1)
x = (x * b) % m;
b= (b * b) % m;
}
return x; 
}
```

This section is just my own function for modular exponentiation and simplification according to: a ^ b (mod n) = a ^ c (mod n) * a ^ d (mod n) where c + d = b. It is to allow large values to be used quickly (and also avoids a floating point error). This function works fine by itself (lots of answers have been checked using wolfram alpha) but I have included it in case there is some kind of error when combined with my array.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long p = 101;
    unsigned long long q = 103;
    int e = 7;
    unsigned long long n = p * q;
    std::string s = "ab";
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)

    {
        std::cout << modExp (returnVal(s[i]), e, n);
    }
}
```

This is where I am having my problem, I am trying to use the array to combine "ab" to form "1011" to then perform the RSA algorithm. **At the moment it is performing 10 ^ 7 (mod 10403) =** *2717* **and 11 ^ 7 (mod 10403) =** *2352* **and giving an output of "***27172352***". What I want to happen is for it to perform 1011 ^ 7 (mod 10403) = 2122** and give this as the output (I put that part in bold for those people who skipped straight to the problem).

Obviously my attempt at using an array to combine "ab" to "1011" is wrong. My question is why is it wrong? Is there a way of adapting it to make it correct? and if not what new method should I employ in order to combine the numbers together?

I'm sorry if the question is a bit long, but I'd rather be too specific than too vague, thanks for any feedback, I'm going to paste my code below so that it's all together in one place. (Also, I am using unsigned long long as normally p and q would be much larger)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x - 87;
}

unsigned long long modExp(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m)
{
unsigned long long remainder;
int x = 1;

while (e != 0)
{
remainder = e % 2;
e= e/2;

if (remainder == 1)
x = (x * b) % m;
b= (b * b) % m;
}
return x;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long p = 101;
    unsigned long long q = 103;
    int e = 7;
    unsigned long long n = p * q;
    std::string s = "ab";
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)

    {
        std::cout << modExp (returnVal(s[i]), e, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should think about the answer you are getting (27172352) and the operation you are performing (mod 10403). Clearly the answer cannot be right since the answer must be in the range 0..10402.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with arrays. What you're really stuck on here is *how to decode a hex string*. You can search for that and find answers here and elsewhere. Note that you're invoking `modExp()` once for each character in the string. What you want is to decode the string and call `modExp` once on the result.

Comment: Yes, it is giving **2717** as the answer to the first number in the array and 2352 as the second number to give **2717** 2352. This is the basis of my problem.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I think you misread the code and/or explanation. That output (27272352) is the combined (concatenated) output of two calculations mod 10403.

Comment: Thanks @dvnrrs, what is a hex string?

Comment: A number "written" in hexadecimal.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would hexadecimal help?

Comment: @dvnrrs, yes, I know, I wondered if the OP did. (Sorry, its the teacher in me.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

All you need to do is to make `returnVal` accept either a `char *` or a `std::string` and pass it the whole string you have. It should then convert the characters one by one and add (after you multiply the out variable by 100, assuming that you want to stick with decimal numbers) to a (possibly huge) integer output. Although, I'd recommend using hex instead as it should be way faster (bitwise shift vs multiplication by 100).

Edit:

The function would look similar to this:

```
unsigned long long returnVal(char *str, size_t length){

    unsigned long long result = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;++i){
        // Do stuff :D
    }

    return result;

}
```

I changed int to `unsigned long long` because the values will become large quite fast. In real world implementation it would be too small anyway though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I'll definitely read up on hexadecimal, how would I go about making `returnVal` accept a `char *` or a `std::string`?

Comment: Just change the argument it takes, then loop through all of the characters and handle them one by one. Remember to pass the **length** argument if you decide to use C strings (`char *`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm ok at the "mathsy" stuff but I really struggle with the terminology. Which part is the argument and how do I go about changing it? Thanks for the help, I know that my stupidity must be frustrating!

Comment: Is this instead of or as well as the original function? Thanks again, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: The whole point is to process the whole string at once and return one big integer instead of processing it in one character chunks and returning a bunch of integers. And if the new function can do that, you don't really need the old one.

Comment: So would this go inside of int main()? again, thank you

Comment: Nope. You should consider re-reading the chapter about functions, it would make it all easier for you.

Comment: I've had a go, but I can only get it to produce value of the first character of the string `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int returnVal(char *str, size_t length){

    int result = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;++i)
    {
    result = (int) *str - 87;
    }

    return result;

}

int main()
{
    cout << returnVal ("word",3) << endl;
}
`this gives 32, which is correct for w.

Answer (score 0):

"Obviously my attempt at using an array to combine "ab" to "1011" is wrong."

Sure, each element in the string array is a separate letter, s[ 0 ] == 'a', s[ 1 ] == 'b'.
There is no way how the array elements would be 'combined'.

You can combine 2-digit decimal numbers as so:

```
int left  = returnVal('a');  // decimal 10
int right = returnVal('b');  // decimal 11

int result = (left *= 100)  + right;   // 1000 + 11 = 1011
```

See: [Positional numeral system](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/)

P.S. And what the "ab" means in your implementation of RSA?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Could this be applied to things which are longer than 2 letters? e.g If if wanted to convert "abc" or "word"? would it have to be some form of loop and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think "ab" is a shortened for simplicity either message or encryption key. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Convert "abc" to decimal 101112? The same way, you just need to "shift" extra left decimal numbers by multiplying on greater multiplier: 10*10000 + 11*100 + 12. You can make a function to convert this but track int overflow.
Please, read about [positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) :)

Maybe it will be better to work with binary numbers and use built-in  binary shift << operations?

Comment: The "ab" is just a random input. Eventually I'm hoping for it to be an entire sentence.

Comment: Would an efficient way of doing this to make it so that s[n] is multiplied by 100 ^ n, s[n-1] by 100 ^ [n-1] ... s[1] * 100, s[0] * 100 ^ 0 and summing the results?

Comment: Yes, correct, it is the idea of positional notation.
But then you'll stuck with the restrictions of representation of input string bits in long long. 
And why do you need to valuate reminder of the whole string? You can cipher it [letter by letter](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/txt/rsa.html)

Comment: I think that my main problem with letter by letter is the input for the decrypt algorithm, I'm only doing it for a word and an input of one large number just seemed "cleaner".

Comment: If you are thinking about efficiency consider that multiplying on the power of 2 is much faster and can be coded with [binary shift operator <<](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/).
Good exercise will be implement with decimal arithmetics and then switch to binary.

Comment: Doesn't transferring the encrypted data letter by letter open you up to some very easy frequency analysis?

Comment: @Alex enciphering letter by letter is about as secure as a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher and really isn't worth implementing RSA to do.

Comment: @MichaelRad yes, but you're doing it as a sample, I think? In practice only AES key (256 bit) is coding with RSA and not the whole message.

Comment: I suppose, but if I'm going to do it, it definitely needs to be at least somewhat secure! I'm trying to apply a loop to the answer you gave